# What is the English equivalent of「ひとこと欄」?

Tags: words

I believe this a kind of word-game, but cannot find a reference to it...

Comment: How is said game played?  `ひとこと` means "a/one word" and `欄` means "column".

Comment: my mistake, as below, not a word game at all but an "extra information" field for a form

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ひとこと欄 is not the name of a game.  It means “a place for a short message.”  It is often found at the end of various forms.  For example, an application form of a fitness center may have ひとこと欄 at the end with a sentence such as “If you have any suggestions or concerns, please write them here.”

I do not know its English equivalent, but I post this as an answer because japanese.stackexchange.com is a website for questions about Japanese, not for questions about English.

Comment: I guess just "comment box"? It's worth pointing out that 欄 is a pretty common word for text fields (e.g. in browsers), like 名前欄 (box into which you put your name). I saw someone refer to some box on Twitter as 「お気に入り」欄 ('favourites' section). The Facebook status update box is 近況欄.